# how to append a line with sed/awk after specific text

Tags: awk, sed

i would like to translate this input file using sed or awk:

```
input
1 AA
3 BB
5 CC

output
1 AA
3 BB
3 GG
5 CC
```

the closest syntax I found on this site `sed -i '/^BB:/ s/$/ GG/'` file   but it does `3 BB GG`.  What I need is similar to a vi yank, paste & regex replace.
can this be done with sed or awk? thanks
Rand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk is a fine choice for this:

```
awk '{print $0} $2=="BB"{print $1,"GG"}' yourfile.txt
```

That will print the line `{print $0}`. And then if the second field in the line is equal to "BB", it will print the first field in the line (the number) and the text "GG".

Example in use:

```
>echo "1 AA\n3 BB\n4 RR" | awk '{print $0} $2=="BB"{print $1,"GG"}'
1 AA
3 BB
3 GG
4 RR
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ]*) BB$/&\n\1 GG/' file
```

Output:

```
1 AA
3 BB
3 GG
5 CC
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/BB/p;s//GG/' file
```

If the line contains the required string print it then substitute another string for it.

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk '1; /BB/ && $2="GG"' input
1 AA
3 BB
3 GG
5 CC
```

`1` prints the record. If there was `BB` in the record just printed, replace it with `GG` and print again.